# Multiple File Upload Using Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am facing issue with multiple files upload using Angular 4.

Here I am trying to append the multiple files in getFileDetails() but only file is selecting and if I choose another file it is getting replaced with the new file but **actual expectation** is they need to append each other and using post method I need to pass the json.

app.component.html:

```
    <div>
      <h1>{{title}}!</h1>
    <ng-container>
          <input type="file" id="file" multiple (change)="getFileDetails($event)">
           <button (click)="uploadFiles()">Upload</button>
      </ng-container>
    </div
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http/src/response';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Upload Multiple Files in Angular 4';

  constructor (private httpService: HttpClient) {  }


  ngOnInit () {  }
  myFiles:string [] = [];
  sMsg:string = '';

  getFileDetails (e) {
    //console.log (e.target.files);
    for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) { 
      this.myFiles.push(e.target.files[i]);
    }
  }

  uploadFiles () {
    const frmData = new FormData();

    for (var i = 0; i < this.myFiles.length; i++) { 
      frmData.append("fileUpload", this.myFiles[i]);
    }

    this.httpService.post('url', frmData).subscribe(
      data => {
        // SHOW A MESSAGE RECEIVED FROM THE WEB API.
        this.sMsg = data as string;
        console.log (this.sMsg);
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log (err.message);    // SHOW ERRORS IF ANY.
      }
    );
  }
}
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Expected json:

```
[{
   "attachmentName": "content-infographic.txt",
   "attachedFile": ""
},
{
  "attachmentName": "infographic.png",
   "attachedFile": ""
}]
```

How can I correct the code to fix the issue?

Comment: A now-deleted answer [pointed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49798046/472495).

Answer (score 0):

I used the below within a PHP API making the first parameter of the append function a string array. Replace it in your loop like this:

```
frmData.append("fileUpload[]", this.myFiles[i]);
```

The only change is the added square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename files automatically by current date before upload it on server, Use the following code

```
var d = new Date();
var msec = Date.parse(d);
for (var i = 0; i < this.myFiles.length; i++) { 
   frmData.append("fileUpload", this.myFiles[i], this.myFiles[i].name + msec);
}
```